# how to resolve The system cannot find the file specified error?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

for a project I need to read a csv file containing pokemon data I try to create a method allowing me to look for the data in my csv file like this:

```java
private final String fileName = "./data/pokedex.csv";
String line = "";
private final String separator = ",";
private List<String> getPokeInfoById(int id) {
        int i = 0;
        List<String> info = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i == id) {
                    try (Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(line.split(","))) {
                        info = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
                    }
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return info;
    }
```

but java says:

```java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data\pokedex.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:155)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:110)
    [...]
```

here is what my src look like:

```
    C:.
├───controleur
├───data
│       grid_types.csv
│       moves.csv
│       pokedex.csv
│
├───img
├───model
│   │   Pokemon.java
│   │   Type.java
│   │
│   └───analyzer
│           Pokedex.java
│
└───test
        PokedexTest.java
```

Comment: What is the value of fileName? And check that file exist in this path.

Comment: By passing a path to a file that actually exists. Note that your path is a relative path, and is thus resolved against the **current** directory, which is the directory from which the java command is executed. Just like when you type `notepad data\pokedex.csv`, it looks for the file pokedex.csv in the data directory contained in the current directory.

Comment: I added my folder tree, my method is in pokedex.java and I try to use it in PokedexTest.java everything seems normal to me

Comment: You're completely missing the point. Read my comment again. The name of your classes is completely irrelevant. What matters is the **current** directory. If you execute `java MyProgram` from `c:\ `, it will look for the file `c:\data\pokedex.csv`. If you execute `java MyProgram` from `c:\foo\bar\baz`, it will look for the file `c:\foo\bar\baz\data\pokedex.csv`

Comment: I used, `System.out.println(new File("."). getAbsolutePath());` to see where I was and I was able to see it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seemed that my path was wrong because I didn't paid attention on what my current directory was using

```java
System.out.println(new File("."). getAbsolutePath());
```

helped me locate myself and found the right path

Answer (score 0):

Try providing full path in the filename

Comment: so issue will be that my project needs to be put on a usb drive so he full path will change :/